# How to write HTML code in $rootScope variable using angularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to change the value of a label in my HTML page on an event,is it possible to insert html code into the variable?

The `HTML` code is like:

```
<div ng-controller="welcomeCon" ><label>{{ welcomemsg }}</label></div>
```

and in some `controller` in the script:

```
$rootScope.welcomemsg="You are not logged in,please log in or register"
```

Is there a way to make the words `log in` and `register` to be links?
If no, I would be happy if someone could guide me what to do in alternative.

Thanks

Comment: Use `$root.welcomemsg`

Comment: why not use $scope? There is just one $rootScope per angular module. It's like a global variable.

Comment: @devqon I am using it but I don't know how to nest in it `<a href...></a>`

Comment: @sisyphus because I am working on a single page application

Comment: please show your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as the other answers suggest by using the `$sce` service or `ng-bind-html`, but I would object to that approach because the links won't change, so why do it by defining the html in your code instead of in the html.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
<ul class="my-menu">
    <li ng-if="$root.loggedIn">
        <a href="url/to/logout">Logout</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="!$root.loggedIn">
        You are not logged in, please <a href="login">login</a> or <a href="register">register</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Use $sce service. Here is the sample example

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller("welcomeCon", function($scope,$sce){
  $scope.loginHtml = "You are not logged in,please <a href=''>log in</a> or <a href=''>register</a>";
  $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.loginHtml);  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="welcomeCon">
  <div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

> OR you can use **ngSanitize** module

```js
angular.module('app',["ngSanitize"])
.controller("test", function($scope){
  $scope.html = "You are not logged in,please <a href=''>log in</a> or <a href=''>register</a>";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-sanitize.js"></script>



<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  <div ng-bind-html="html">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will upvote if you also include his usecase (include the `You are not logged in,please log in or register` text from the `$rootScope`)

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-bind-html directive to bind HTML to the model value. See link: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind-html.asp

You need to use **ngSanitize** module in your application. Include **angular-santize.js** file to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already got your answer, but just to put this out there...

You can also do this using a very simple directive as like a child view, and avoid using `$rootScope` all together. This promotes reuse across applications, and follows angular's modular approach of breaking things down into small parts (in this case *very* small parts!).

**welcomeMessage.js**

```
app.directive('welcomeMessage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "welcomeMessage.html"
  };
});
```

**welcomeMessage.html**

```
<p>
  You are not logged in, please 
  <a href="/login">log in</a> or 
  <a href="/register">register</a>
</p>
```

**Sample Usage (in your index.html)**

```
<welcome-message />
```

**[Sample Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/rEUpN5sUl4f5CIzlHZXJ?p=preview)**